# Accuracy of a location in a label

Tags: label, cllocation

I am still a beginner developer in xcode and the entire objective-C.

I am making an app that you can see your coordinates on a screen ( its still in the beginning phase)

But the user cant see how accurate the coordinates are... I can see in the debug area, but the user that uses the app cant see it.

How do I add that in my code?

My code is currently :

```
#import "CurrentLocationViewController.h"

@interface CurrentLocationViewController ()

@end

@implementation CurrentLocationViewController
{
CLLocationManager *_locationManager;
CLLocation *_location;

BOOL _updatingLocation;

NSError *_lastLocationError;


}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

[self updateLabels];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)getLocation:(id)sender
{
[self startLocationManager];
[self updateLabels];

}


- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

}
  return self;
}
```

## pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"did fail with error %@",error);

if (error.code == kCLErrorLocationUnknown) {
    return;
}

[self stopLocationManager];
_lastLocationError = error;

[self updateLabels];

}

- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];
NSLog(@"didUpdateLocations %@", newLocation);

_lastLocationError = nil;
_location = newLocation;
[self updateLabels];
}


- (void) updateLabels

{
if (_location !=nil) {
    self.latitudeLabel.text = [NSString     stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",_location.coordinate.latitude];
    self.longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",_location.coordinate.longitude];
    self.tagButton.hidden = NO;
    self.messageLabel.text = @"Here are your coordinates";
}
else {
    self.latitudeLabel.text= @"";
    self.longitudeLabel.text= @"";
    self.adressLabel.text= @"";
    self.tagButton.hidden = YES;

    NSString *statusMessage;
    if (_lastLocationError != nil) {
        if ([_lastLocationError.domain isEqualToString:kCLErrorDomain] && _lastLocationError.code == kCLErrorDenied) {
            statusMessage = @"Location Services Disabled";
        } else {
            statusMessage = @"Error getting location";
        }
    } else if (![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
        statusMessage = @"Location Services Disabled";
    } else if (_updatingLocation) {
        statusMessage = @"Searching...";
    } else {
        statusMessage = @"Press the Button to start";
    }

    self.messageLabel.text = statusMessage;

}
```

}

```
- (void) startLocationManager
{
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
    _locationManager.delegate = self;
    _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    _updatingLocation = YES;
}
}


- (void) stopLocationManager
{
if (_updatingLocation) {
    [_locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    _locationManager.delegate = nil;
    _updatingLocation = NO;
}
}
```

@end

@end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`horizontalAccuracy` is a property of CLLocation. It reports the current horizontal accuracy in meters. The meaning of this is that your true position is up to `horizontalAccuracy` meters from the reported position in any direction.
Referring to your `updateLabels` code, you can access `_location.horizontalAccuracy` and display it along with the other information.
There is a similar property `verticalAccuracy`.